# How many numbers can be formed using $1,3,4,5,6,9$ only once and divisible by $7$ or $11$ or $13$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

> How many numbers can be formed using $1,3,4,5,6,9$ only once and divisible by $7$ or $11$ or $13$?

I know the divisibility rules but they are not helping here. how do i solve this? Also the question is unclear that do I need to use all of them or not.
My work -
I think if it was "$7$ **and** $11$ **and** $13$" then I would solve it by this -
any number in form $abcabc$ is divisible by $1001 = 7\times 13 \times 11$. Then the answer would be $\binom{6}{3}$? Correct me if i am wrong.

I will like to know both solutions. i.e. "$7$ **or** $11$ **or** $13$" and "$7$ **and** $11$ **and** $13$".

Comment: This isn't a "do your homework for free" service, what have you tried already?

Comment: "only once" usually means exactly once in problems like this.

Comment: @Travis added my work :)

Comment: I think the answer for "and" will be $^6p_3$ = 6*5*4. ??

Comment: Number $abcabc$ uses each $a,$,$b$ and $c$ twice. You cant use numbers twice.

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak Opps. Then I am completely wrong :(

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak Then I think there is no solution for "and" right?

Comment: The divisibility test for $11$ is easy enough.  It appears there are $2(3!)=72$ multiples of $11$.  Unfortunately, the other $2$ divisibility tests aren't as easy and it could be a pain to find how many numbers are multiples of more than $1$ of the $3$ options.

Answer (score 0):

The six-digit numbers using the digits 1,3,4,5,6,9 that are divisible by $7$, $11$ or $13$ don't seem to satisfy any obvious pattern so I'm not sure there is a nice mathematical solution (maybe there is), but it's very easy for a computer to iterate over all permutations of the list 1,3,4,5,6,9 and test divisibility.

In this way you find the number of solutions divisible by $7$ OR $11$ OR $13$ is 180; and the number of solutions divisible by $7$ AND $11$ AND $13$ is 18.

Comment: Is that for using each number once?  I believe the OP has determined there are no solutions for "OR".